# How to properly fallback on css grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a simple grid (3x3 at most, which fills in top to bottom left to right) of squares. This is a simple task to achieve with either grid for flexbox. However the DOM that I write for either seems either incompatible or requires too much styling to be worth supporting both.

My flexbox looks like

```css
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tile {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
    <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
    <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
    <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
    <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
    <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
    <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The grid looks like

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 3, 1fr );
 grid-template-rows: repeat( 3, 1fr );
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
</div>
```

So my question boils down to: **How do I get around the use of div.col and still have a working flexbox and not clutter up my grid css.**

I've tried using `flex-wrap: row` to avoid the div.col wrappers. This causes the tiles in flexbox to wrap properly and create the 3x3 grid but then I have to specify a height. I need the tiles to respond properly both in width and height without having to specify either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried using `flex-wrap: row` to avoid the `div.col` wrappers. This causes the tiles in flexbox to wrap properly and create the 3x3 grid but then I have to specify a height. I need the tiles to respond properly both in width and height without having to specify either.

But width and height are specified in Grid, as well. The only difference is that with Grid you specify the dimensions at the *container level*, and with Flex you specify the dimensions at the *item level*.

Dimensions in Grid:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 3, 1fr );  /* <-- width */
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 3, 1fr );     /* <-- height */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 3, 1fr );
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 3, 1fr );
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
</div>
```

Dimensions in Flex (from my example below):

```
.tile {
  flex: 1 0 30%;  /* <-- width */
  height: 30%;    /* <-- height */
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.tile {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="tile" style="background: blue"></div>
</div>
```